# Are there nondegenerate simplices that "look like" degenerate simplices?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Is there a simplicial set $X$ in which there is an edge $(f\colon C\to D)\in X_1$ (i.e., $d_0(f)=D$ and $d_1(f)=C$) and a 2-simplex $\tau\in X_2$ such that $$d_0(\tau)=s_0(D),\quad d_1(\tau)=f, \quad d_2(\tau)=f\qquad (\ast)$$
and $\tau$ is *nondegenerate*?

I observed that the *degenerate* simplex of the form $\tau = s_1(f)$ has the property $(\ast)$, and my question is kind of asking about the converse. (One approach of showing that there isn't such an example would be to let $\tau$ be a 2-simplex with $(\ast)$, and then to show that $\tau=s_1(f)$. But just using the simplicial identities this seems pretty hopeless.)

Note that nerves of categories can't provide such an example. But if there is a *singular simplicial set* for which this is true, I prefer to be given such an example.

Comment: By singular simplicial set you mean an object in the image of the usual functor $\textbf{Top} \to \textbf{Set}$? Then yes, there are many examples. For example, you might look at the singular simplicial set of the sphere $S^2$: then you can even find a non-degenerate 2-simplex of the kind you want that is even non-homotopic to a degenerate 2-simplex.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, I see! Thank you, sir.